# Image enhancement using LabVIEW

Tags: matlab, image-processing, labview

I'm trying to make a program to enhance an image in LabVIEW. I have already program in matlab codes, but its some built-in functions are not working in LabVIEW since it is not present in LabVIEW mathscript module. The algorithm used to enhance the image is written below

1. input image in RGB
2. Contrast stretching of the model
3. RGB to HSI
4. contrast stretching of S&I
5. display the RGB image
   So please help to implement this algorithm in LabVIEW

Comment: If you cannot run your code in the mathscript module, you have to change strategy and re-code your algortihm in pure Labview. If you're a beginner in Labview, why don't you read the documentation first ? For such basic image processing, the tools from `IMAQ vision` will be greatly enough.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB can make a dll from your m file (including all of your built-in functions) and then you can call that dll from your Labview. To do so, you need to install [MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR)](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) on your machine (You don't need that, if you have already installed MATLAB).

If you want to have **standalone dll** file (not using matlab runtime), you need to use [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) (which probably you need to buy it).

I recommend to use MCR first because it is easier to start with and more flexible in using MATLAB features.